# Selected Items are unchecked in Android?

Tags: android, list, listview

In my Apps, I used ListView to select a Items to be Ordered. When I select the Items to Order it get checked and it is added in the Ordering page. If I go back to Main page and If again I come to the Item List ,The selected Items will be unchecked but selected Items are present in the Ordering page. 
Selected Items should be checked until manually removed. Please help me to solve this.

Here is my code :

```
     public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {


      final  ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selecteditemlistview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.textViewSelectedText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectedtext);
            holder.price=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectitemprice);
            holder.image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectitemimage);
            holder.qty=(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectqty);
            holder.total=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);               
            holder.delete = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete);

            holder.uncheck = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bcheck);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else 
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        String amount=holder.qty.getText().toString();
        final Double price1=Double.parseDouble(itemprice.get(position));
        int qut=Integer.parseInt(holder.qty.getText().toString());
        Double total=(price1*qut);
        holder.textViewSelectedText.setText(arr1.get(position));
        holder.price.setText(itemprice.get(position));
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(itemimage.get(position));
        holder.total.setText(String.valueOf(total));


        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 arr1.remove(position);
                 itemimage.remove(position);
                 itemprice.remove(position);
               //  holder.uncheck.setChecked(false);
                 View parent = (View)v.getParent(); 
                 CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)parent.findViewById(R.id.bcheck); 
                 if ((holder.arr1==true)&&(holder.uncheck.isChecked()))
                     {holder.uncheck.setChecked(false);
                     }
                 notifyDataSetChanged();


            }

        });



      holder.qty.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!hasFocus)
            {

                 int position = v.getId();      
                final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                Caption.setFocusable(true); 
                holder.qty.setFocusable(true);
                int q=Integer.parseInt(holder.qty.getText().toString());
                Double result=(price1 * q);
                System.out.println(result);              
                holder.total.setText(String.valueOf(result));
                                }
        }
    });


        return convertView;     
    }

    class ViewHolder      
    {
         protected boolean arr1;
        public CheckBox uncheck;
        public Button delete;
         public TextView mTextView;

        TextView textViewSelectedText = null;
        TextView price=null;
        ImageView image=null;      
        EditText qty=null;
        TextView total=null;
    }
```

Comment: show us your code of adapter.

Comment: I have added my CustomAdapter code to the question.

Comment: So you have two activities? The first one creates a new one, where you can select items?

Comment: yaa your right. How can I solve now?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I know is a manual one. You have to pass a list of selected items to your ListView.

**your main activity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourListViewActivity.class);
// parcelables or a List of indexes (your choice but I prefer Parcelables)
// I assume that you have your selection stored in a List to work with it
// make SomeKey as a constant
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("SomeKey", listOfYourObjectsAsParcelables);
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

**selection activity** - assuming that it extends ListActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // load selection from the intent
    List<YourParcelableObject> parcelables = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("SomeKey");

    if (parcelables != null) {
        // convert to YourObject
        List<YourObject> selectedObjects = convert(parcelables);

        // iterate over the list and check items        
        for (int i = 0; i < getListView().getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
            YourObject object = (YourObject) getListView().getAdapter().getItem(i);
            if (selectedObjects.contains(object)) {
                getListView().setItemChecked(i, true);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Note that this is only a snippet and I did not test it but it should give you the idea.